# XPATH to eliminate characters

Tags: xpath

In the below link i have Source : Reuters with copyright , how do i eliminate all the characters after reuters.

http://www.rediff.com/cricket/report/confident-australia-move-on-to-perth-with-urn-on-their-minds-ashes-2017-18-pix/20171208.htmt

"Source: source
© Copyright 2019 Reuters Limited. All rights reserved. Republication or redistribution of Reuters content, including by framing or similar means, is expressly prohibited without the prior written consent of Reuters. Reuters shall not be liable for any errors or delays in the content, or for any actions taken in reliance thereon."

This text is under //div[@class='grey1']/text()[2]

I know that i have to use substring functions, but i am not quite sure how to use it though.

Is this correct ? 
substring-before(//div[@class='grey1']/text()[2],'Limited')

Is this the correct way to eliminate characters ?

Comment: What is your exact desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting I need to remove all the characters after '© Copyright 2019 Reuters' and just display this '© Copyright 2019 Reuters'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the structure of that text snippet is always the same (for example, that the word "Reuters" is always followed by "Limited"), this xpath expression should work:

```
substring-after(substring-before( //div[@class='grey1']/text()[2],' Limited'),' © ' )
```

Output:

> Copyright 2019 Reuters